# How to count frequency of pairs in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Right now I am able to count the frequency of each word in a list.

```
    >>> list =['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'c']

frequency = {}
for w in words:
    frequency[w] = frequency.get(w, 0) + 1
return frequency
```

It gives me this output:

> {'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c: 2'}

But what I'd like for it to give me is the frequency of pairs for each list item.  For example, 'b' comes after 'a' 1 time and 'c' comes after 'a' 2 times.

> {'a':{'b':1,'c':2},'b':{'a':1},'c':{'a':1}}

How would I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 13):

If you're willing to accept a slightly different format, it's easy to get the pairwise counts using `collections.Counter` and `zip`:

```
>>> seq = list("abacac")
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(zip(seq, seq[1:]))
>>> c
Counter({('a', 'c'): 2, ('b', 'a'): 1, ('c', 'a'): 1, ('a', 'b'): 1})
```

If you really want the format you gave, you have a few options, but one way would be to use `itertools.groupby` to collect all the pairs starting with the same element together:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> grouped = groupby(sorted(zip(seq, seq[1:])), lambda x: x[0])
>>> {k: dict(Counter(x[1] for x in g)) for k,g in grouped}
{'a': {'c': 2, 'b': 1}, 'c': {'a': 1}, 'b': {'a': 1}}
```

Comment: What if it's a list of lists like [['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'c'],['a','f']] and I want to iterate through both lists to get {'a': {'c': 2, 'b': 1, 'f':1}, 'c': {'a': 1}, 'b': {'a': 1}} ?

Answer (score 1):

```
mylist = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'c']

freq = {}
for idx, char in enumerate(mylist):
    if idx == len(mylist) - 1: break

    if char not in freq: freq.setdefault(char, {})

    if mylist[idx + 1] in freq[char]:
        freq[char][mylist[idx + 1]] += 1
    else:
        freq[char].setdefault(mylist[idx + 1], 1)

print freq
```

**Output**

```
{'a': {'c': 2, 'b': 1}, 'c': {'a': 1}, 'b': {'a': 1}}
```