# pandas.Series : how to get rate of next value

Tags: python, pandas

About pandas, I want to know how to get rate of next value. Below series is a sample.

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([1,2,1,1,1,3])
>>> s
0    1
1    2
2    1
3    1
4    1
5    3

# What I wanna get are below rates.
# 1 to 2 : 1/5(0.2)
# 2 to 1 : 1/5(0.2)
# 1 to 1 : 2/5(0.4)
# 1 to 3 : 1/5(0.2)
```

Sorry for bad description, but is there anyone who know how to do this?

Comment: Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19532360/how-to-count-frequency-of-pairs-in-a-list

Comment: awesome... Really appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution with [strides](https://rigtorp.se/2011/01/01/rolling-statistics-numpy.html), aggregate count by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and division by length of `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([1,2,1,1,1,3])

def rolling_window(a, window):
    shape = a.shape[:-1] + (a.shape[-1] - window + 1, window)
    strides = a.strides + (a.strides[-1],)
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape=shape, strides=strides)


df1 = pd.DataFrame(rolling_window(s.values, 2), columns=['from','to'])

df1 = df1.groupby(['from','to'], sort=False).size().div(len(df1)).reset_index(name='rate')
print (df1)
   from  to  rate
0     1   2   0.2
1     2   1   0.2
2     1   1   0.4
3     1   3   0.2
```